# Error with Ruby gems (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm still getting an error with my gemfile, I can Download all the gems, but at the moment of 'rails server' I'm getting this error:

```
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'will_paginate'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/will_paginate-2.3.15/lib/will_paginate.rb:33:in `require'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/will_paginate-2.3.15/lib/will_paginate.rb:33:in `enable_activerecord'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/will_paginate-2.3.15/lib/will_paginate.rb:88:in `<top (required)>'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/administrador/Documents/forminst4/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    from /home/administrador/Documents/forminst4/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6'
gem 'prawn', '0.8.4'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'will_paginate', '2.3.15'
gem 'net-ldap', '0.3.1'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.10'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

I'll really appreciate it if you can help me with this! Thanks a lot

Edit: I've tried adding "gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'" to my gemfile.. and when I run rails server I get this error

```
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'cancan'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant AbstractController::ViewPaths
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:36:in `<module:Rendering>'
/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:33:in `<module:AbstractController>'....(same as above)
```

Answer (score 0):

just update your gemfile with

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
```

rails 3 or 3+ version need above version for will paginate

refer this https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't work neither... I'm getting the following error:

ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'cancan'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant AbstractController::ViewPaths

Comment: did you install node.js if no then run this command 'sudo apt-get install nodejs'

Comment: Yeah, It is installed in my machine. I don't knwo if the ruby version (2.4.0) has something in between.

Comment: yes it is possible, try to switch ruby 2.3, hope it will work